# Android can't get view's position

Tags: android, dynamic, view, position

In my app I adding views programmatically in `onCreate` method, using `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` because I need width of parent `TableLayout` to set suitable size of views.

After that all I need store positions of added views, but methods `getX()`, `getY()` and `getLeft()`, `getTop()` always returns 0. `getLocationInWindow()` or  `getLocationInScreen()` returns positions of parent `TableLayout`. It happens regardless of where I call this methods: in `onGlobalLayout()` callback of `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` or in `onWindowFocusChanged()`

So what should I do, any ideas?

for more details see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264054/android-get-location-of-dynamicly-added-views)